# Add row to dataframe, based on condition (matching ID)

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have two dataframes. I want to add to df1 a row out of df2, based on conditions. The conditions are basically the ID. Imagine you have df1 as so..

```
    ID   Val1     Val2       
1   1       1        3          
2   2       3        2             
3   3       1        2             
4   4       3        4               
5   5       2        3
```

and to that df1 you want to add a specific row out of df2, which looks like this..

```
    ID      A        B      
1   2       4        9          
2   1       5        7             
3   3       2        6             
4   5       4        9               
5   4       2        8
```

So the new dataframe should be automatically matching/merging the df1 and df2, based on ID, and keep in mind, I can't simply use cbind, because the order is different.

```
    ID   Val1     Val2      A      B     
1   1       1        3      5      7
2   2       3        2      4      9       
3   3       1        2      2      6       
4   4       3        4      4      9          
5   5       2        3      2      8
```

I have used semi_join, as such

```
df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(semi_join(df2, df1, by = "ID"))
```

but I get NA's for df2. The dataframes are connteced by ID, but where the values of A and B should be, there is only NA, without any exception. What could I be doing wrong, is there maybe another better alternative solution to this?

Comment: I should add, that in my actual dataframes, they don*t have the same length. df1 is way longer, has more rows than df2, but it needs to be this way, because df2 contains info, that just needs to be added into df, whenever the ID matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `merge` which will take care of rows order

```
merge(df1 , df2 , by = "ID")
```

- output

```
  ID Val1 Val2 A B
1  1    1    3 5 7
2  2    3    2 4 9
3  3    1    2 2 6
4  4    3    4 2 8
5  5    2    3 4 9
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked just the way I wanted to!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `dplyr` for your example, here is a solution using `left_join`. That is the kind of join in the situation like yours, where you want to add information to `df1` from `df2` while preserving the format of `df1`.

When you use joins, there is no need to use `bind_rows`, and a `semi_join` is a so-called filtering join that won't do what you're after here.

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 |> 
  left_join(df2)
```

Output:

```r
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID  Val1  Val2     A     B
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     3     5     7
2     2     3     2     4     9
3     3     1     2     2     6
4     4     3     4     2     8
5     5     2     3     4     9
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df1 <- read_table("ID   Val1     Val2
1       1        3          
2       3        2             
3       1        2             
4       3        4               
5       2        3")

df2 <- read_table("ID      A        B
2       4        9          
1       5        7             
3       2        6             
5       4        9               
4       2        8")
```